# Using backbone.js with Jenkins's JSONP API

Tags: backbone.js, jsonp

I'm trying to use [backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) to wrap the [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) REST API.

To get job details, one performs a GET on a URL like this:

https://jenkins.example.com/jenkins/job/test-job/api/json/?jsonp=jQuery18207471012645401061_1351262357807&_=1351262357850

My very simple backbone app looks like this:

```
$(function () {
   var Job = Backbone.Model.extend({
      defaults:{
         displayName:'not set'
      }
   });

   var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
      el:$("#hudApp"),

      initialize:function () {
         var job = new Job;
         job.url = 'https://jenkins.example.com/jenkins/job/test-job/api/json/?jsonp=?';
         job.fetch({dataType:"jsonp"});

         alert(job.get('displayName'));
      });
   });

   var app = new AppView;
});
```

I can see the HTTP requests hitting my Jenkins server, and receiving responses like:

```
jQuery18207471012645401061_1351262357807(
{
description: "build a nice test job",
displayName: "test-job",
}
)
```

However, my model is not getting updated (the `alert()` always displays "not set").

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Complete operator error. Apparently, the "A" in AJAX stands for "asynchronous"...

I just needed to change my fetching code to:

```
        job.fetch({
           dataType:"jsonp",
           success: function(model, response) {
              alert(model.get('displayName'));
           }
        });
```

Sorry about the stupid question. Hopefully this is at least useful to Google, as I had lots of trouble finding examples of how to use Backbone with JSONP.